# Caching whether or not an item in a database exists

Tags: node.js, caching, redis

I have a simple caching mechanism that involves me checking if an item is in a database cache (`table:id#id_number`), then if not I check if that item is in the database. If it is in the database, then I cache that item. If it is not, then I obviously don't.

The issue is this, in my current situation, going to be happening frequently. Every time someone visits the front page, I will see if id 10 exists, then if id 9 exists, etc.

If id 9 doesn't exist, nothing will be cached and my server will constantly be hitting my database every time someone visits my front page.

My solution right now is very dirty and could easily lead to confusion in the future. I am now caching whether or not an id in the database *probably* exists (`pexists:table:id#id_number`). If it doesn't probably exist, I just assume it doesn't exist, or if the cache isn't set. If it does probably exist, I check if it's in the cache. If it's not, only *then* will I hit my database. I will then cache the result from my database and whether or not it exists.

I am asking if there is a better way of achieving this effect.

```
             /* 
             This method takes an amount (how many posts you need) and start
             (the post id we want to start at). If, for example,
             the DB has ids 1, 2, 4, 7, 9, and we ask for
             amount=3 and start=7, we should return the items
             with ids 7, 4, and 2. 
            */
            const parametersValidity = await this.assureIsValidPollsRequestAsync(
                amount,
                start
            );
            const validParameters = parametersValidity.result;
            if (!validParameters) {
                throw new Error(parametersValidity.err);
            }

            let polls = [];
            for (   
                    let i=start, pollId=start; 
                    (i > start - amount && pollId > 0); 
                    i--, pollId--
            ) {
                // There is probably no poll logged in the database.
                if(!(await this.pollProbablyExists(pollId))) {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }

                let poll;
                const cacheHash = `polls:id#${pollId}`;
                if(await cache.existsAsync(cacheHash)) {
                    poll = 
                        await this.findKeysFromCacheHash(
                            cacheHash, 
                            "Id", "Title", "Description", "Option1", "Option2", "AuthorId"
                        );
                } else {
                    // Simulates a slow database retreival thingy
                    // for testing.
                    await new Promise(resolve => {
                        setTimeout(resolve, 500)
                    });

                    poll = await this.getPollById(pollId);

                    if(typeof poll !== "undefined") {
                        this.insertKeysIntoCacheHash(
                            cacheHash, 60 * 60 * 3 /* 3 hours to expire */,
                            poll
                        );
                    }
                }
                if(typeof poll === "undefined") {
                    // This would happen if a user deleted a poll
                    // when the exists:polls:id#poll_id key in cache
                    // hadn't expired yet.
                    cache.setAsync(`exists:${cacheHash}`, 0);
                    cache.expire(`exists:polls:id#${pollId}`, 60 * 60 * 10 /* 10 hours. */);
                    i++;
                } else {
                    polls.push(poll);
                    cache.setAsync(`exists:${cacheHash}`, 1);
                }
            }
            return polls;
```

Comment: Can we see how you're doing it now? (code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to avoid those non-existent keys hitting the database frequently.

If that's the case, a better and simpler way is to cache the non-existent keys.

- If the key exists in database, you can cache it in Redis with the value gotten from database.
- If the key doesn't exist in database, also cache it in Redis, but with a **special** value.

For example, you cache players' score in Redis. If the player doesn't exist, you also cache the key, but with **-1** as the score. When searching the cache, if the key exists but the cached value is **-1**, that means the key doesn't exist in database.